# string.contains(string) match whole word

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, formcollection

In my view,

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)){
<div>
    @Html.TextBox("text_1", " ")
    @Html.TextBox("text_2", " ")
    @if(Session["UserRole"].ToString() == "Manager"){
    @Html.TextBox("anotherText_3", " ")
    }
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

In my controller,

```
public ActionResult Action(FormCollection form){
    if(!form.AllKeys.Contains("anotherText")){
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "AnotherText is missing!");
    }
}
```

I have a form and post to my method, in my method i want to check if a textbox with id that containing "anotherText", but i use .Contains() it always give false which is not found in my formcollection...How can i do so that it check if the textbox of id containing "anotherText" is existed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes sense that the search would fail, since it's not an exact match.

Try using `StartsWith` instead, to see if any key starts with the value you're looking for.

```
if (!form.AllKeys.Any(x => x.StartsWith("anotherText")))
{
    // add error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `string.Contains` which will `return true` if the `string` contains the given **substring**, what you did here is checking if in the `AllKeys` (which is a **Collection**) there is any `Key` (a *single* key - the **sub-item** of the **Collection**) which is of the `string` `"anotherText"`.

```
if(!form.AllKeys.Contains("anotherText"))
```

Consequently, your **sub-item** in the **Collection** is the *entire* `string` itself, not the `substring` of the `string`

Thus your `AllKeys` must really contain an exact `string` that matches it:

```
"anotherText_2", //doesn't match
"anotherText_1", //doesn't match
"anotherText_3", //doesn't match
"anotherText" //matches
```

Compare with `Contains` in a `string`

```
string str = "anotherText_3";
str.Contains("anotherText"); //true, this contains "anotherText"
```

Thus, you should rather check if `Any` of the `Keys` have `"anotherText"`:

```
if (!form.AllKeys.Any(x => x.Contains("anotherText")))
{
    // add error
}
```